# mySQL - convert result to string

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to convert query result into string, for example:

```
SELECT ID, Name, State
```

result is:

```
1    Joe   1
2    Steve 2
3    Ian   1
```

I want to convert State result as follows:

```
1    Jone  NO
2    Steve YES
3    Ian   NO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with:

```
SELECT ID, Name, IF(State = 1, 'NO', 'YES')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, 
       name, 
       case 
          when state = 1 then 'NO' 
          else 'YES'
       end as state_text
from the_table
```